# Group Action - Permutation on the Polynomial

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-actions

I'm trying to check the permutation on the polynomial is a Group Action, but I'm not getting the second axiom. I'm following my lecturer's work --- Examples 2.1 and 2.6 on page 5 on http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf --- I post this first. Can someone please spot the mistake? Thanks.

[image]

**Lecturer did:** For $p \in S_n$ and $ \textbf{v} = (c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}$,
define $ p \cdot \textbf{v} := (c_{p(1)},,\cdots,c_{p(n)}) $. Check $$ p_2 \cdot (\color{green}{p_1 \cdot (v)}) \overset{?}{\mathop{=}}\ (p_2 \cdot p_1)(v)  \tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

LHS = $ \color{maroon}{p_2} \cdot \color{green}{(c_{p_1(1)},,\cdots,c_{p_1(n)})} = \color{green}{{(c_{p_1(\color{maroon}{{p_2}(1)})}}},\cdots,\color{green}{{c_{p_1(\color{maroon}{{p_2}(n)})})} = (c_{(p_1{{p_2})(1)}},\cdots,c_{(p_1{{p_2})(n)}})} $ $\text{since $S_n$ is a group so has associativity.} $

$ = (p_1 \cdot p_2)(v) \neq RHS $. Hence above is NOT a group action.

**I tried:** Define $ p \cdot f(x_1, \cdots,x_n) := f(x_{p(1)},,\cdots,x_{p(n)}) $. Check this is a group action.

LHS of $ (\spadesuit) = \color{maroon}{p_2} \cdot \color{green}{(x_{p_1(1)},,\cdots,c_{x_1(n)})} = \color{green}{{f(x_{p_1(\color{maroon}{{p_2}(1)})}}},\cdots,\color{green}{{x_{p_1(\color{maroon}{{p_2}(n)})})} = f(x_{(p_1{{p_2})(1)}},\cdots,x_{(p_1{{p_2})(n)}})}  = (p_1 \cdot p_2)(v) \neq RHS $

Hence the above is NOT a group action?

Comment: It's right (or contravariant) action. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_group

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is tricky - the two cases look the same, but they're not.  The first one is a *right* action $v \cdot (p_1 \cdot p_2) = (v \cdot p_1) \cdot p_2$, while the second one is a *left* action $p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot f) = (p_1 \cdot p_2) \cdot f$.  To see why, consider these 2 permutations:

$$p_1(1) = 1, p_1(2) = 3, p_1(3) = 2 $$
and
$$p_2(1) = 3, p_2(2) = 2, p_2(3) = 1.$$

Let's write out explicitly what the actions are in the two cases to see the difference.

First, let's work out what the compositions $p_1 \cdot p_2$ and $p_2 \cdot p_1$ are.

The composition $p_1 \cdot p_2$ is:

$$p_1(p_2(1)) = 2, p_1(p_2(2)) = 3, p_1(p_2(3)) = 1$$

while the composition $p_2 \cdot p_1$ is:

$$p_2(p_1(1)) = 3, p_2(p_1(2)) = 1, p_2(p_1(3)) = 2.$$

Observe that they are *not* the same.  We will use these later.

Now let's look at the 2 actions.  The first action is on *vectors*.  By the definition of the first action, $$p_1 \cdot (v_1, v_2, v_3) = (v_{p_1(1)}, v_{p_1(2)}, v_{p_1(3)}) = (v_1, v_3, v_2).$$ In words: $p_1$ acting on a vector *interchanges the second and third coordinates*.  Similarly, $$p_2 \cdot (v_1, v_2, v_3) = (v_3, v_2, v_1)$$ In words: $p_2$ acting on a vector *interchanges the first and third coordinates*.

(In this situation, I find that thinking in words reduces the confusion:  $p_1$ interchanges the *second and third coordinates*, not $v_2$ and $v_3$.  You'll see the difference below.)

Thus, $$p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot v) = p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot (v_1, v_2, v_3)) = p_1 \cdot (v_3, v_2, v_1) = (v_3, v_1, v_2).$$  (If the last equality seems wrong, use the "words" description of $p_1$: Interchange the second and third coordinates.) Now the rightmost term above is $(p_2 \cdot p_1) \cdot v$, not $(p_1 \cdot p_2) \cdot v$.  (Use the calculation of $p_2 \cdot p_1$ above.)

Conclusion: For the first action, on vectors, $p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot v) = (p_2 \cdot p_1) \cdot v$.  So this is not a left action, but a right action.

Now look at the second action, which is not on vectors, but on *real-valued functions on the set of all vectors*. By definition, $$(p_1 \cdot f)(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f(x_{p_1(1)}, x_{p_1(2)}, x_{p_1(3)}) = f(x_1, x_3, x_2).$$

In words: To evaluate $p_1$ applied to a function at a vector, interchange the second and third coordinates of the vector, then apply the function.

Similarly, for $p_2$, the words version is: To evaluate $p_2$ applied to a function at a vector, interchange the first and third coordinates of the vector, then apply the function.

So what is $p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot f)$, applied to a vector?  It is $$(p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot f))(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (p_2 \cdot f)(x_1, x_3, x_2) = f(x_2, x_3, x_1).$$

(Again, using the "words" description may reduce the confusion.)  Now is this last term $p_1 \cdot p_2$ or $p_2 \cdot p_1$ applied to $f$?  It is the former, as you can see from the calculation of $p_1 \cdot p_2$ above.

Conclusion: $p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot f) = (p_1 \cdot p_2) \cdot f$.  This one is a left action.

I hope this clears up why these two cases aren't the same.  Of course, I haven't yet proven that these are actions in general (I've only illustrated it for the particular $p_1$ and $p_2$ above), but hopefully this will give you the right idea for the general proof.

The key point is to remember that with these definitions, we are permuting the *coordinates of the vector* according to $p$, rather than the *indices of the $v$'s* according to $p$.  If we did the latter instead, then the left and right action cases above would be reversed.  See [alias vs alibi](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic446952.files/aliasalibi.pdf) for more discussion of this point.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and get back to this post later.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Harvard iSites platform has retired and so the "alias vs. alibi" link now longer works. (You also referenced it in your comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373136/why-composition-and-dihedral-group-have-reverse-order-of-operation#comment2802569_1376327).) The Wayback machine also doesn't seem to have any knowledge of it as a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it: if the action is

$$p\cdot v:=\left(c_{p(1)},...,c_{p(n)}\right)$$

then *it must be*

$$p_2\left(c_{p_1(1)},...,c_{p_1(n)}\right):=\left(c_{p_2(p(1))},...,c_{p_2(p_1(n))}\right)=\left(c_{p_2\circ p_1(1)},...,c_{p_2\circ p_1(n)}\right)$$

Why do you, and your lecturer, interchange the roles of the index between $\,p_1\,$ and $\,p_2\,$?

With the above I think you won't have problems...

Comment: No, the roles have to be interchanged. The definition of the operation is $(p \cdot v)_i = v_{p(i)}$.  Then $(p_2 \cdot (p_1 \cdot v))_i = (p_1 \cdot v)_{p_2(i)} = v_{p_1(p_2(i))} = ((p_1 \cdot p_2) \cdot v)_i$.  As defined, this is a right action, not a left action.  It would be more natural to write $v \cdot p$ for the action, and then we would have the natural looking law $(v \cdot p_1) \cdot p_2 = v \cdot (p_1 \cdot p_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for posting back. I've uploaded a screenshot of the exact note.

Comment: @Ted, I did *not* do $\,\left(p_2\cdot(p_1\cdot v)\right)_i\,$, but as it's clearly written there $\,p_2(c_{p(i)})\,$ , which is the other side. . Nevertheless I understand your point and see the inversing of the indexes of $\,p_i\,$ and, thus, to avoid problems (right-left action and etc.), to define, from the left as they did, by the inverse. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the action $\sigma:(v_1,\cdots,v_n)\mapsto(v_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,v_{\sigma(n)})$ is not left, is because when you apply a second permutation element $\rho$ to $\sigma v$, $v_{\sigma(1)}$ is the first coordinate of $\sigma v$, not the $\sigma(1)$th, $v_{\sigma(2)}$ is the second coordinate of $\sigma v$, not the $\sigma(2)$th, etc. so we cannot simply apply $\rho$ to the subscript in the seemingly obvious (but naive) way. Instead, we would write $w:=\sigma v=(v_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,v_{\sigma(n)})$, so that we have $w_i=v_{\sigma(i)}$, in which case $w_{\rho(i)}=v_{\sigma(\rho(i))}$ hence $\rho(\sigma v)=(v_{\sigma\rho(1)},\cdots,v_{\sigma\rho(n)})=(\sigma\rho)v$, in which case it is a right action (and it makes more sense to write it as group-element-on-the-right instead).

Answer (score 0):

I fill in Ted's exquisite answer.

---

This is tricky - the two cases look the same, but they're not.
The first one is a *right* action $v \cdot (p_1 \cdot p_2) = (v \cdot p_1) \cdot p_2$,
while the second one is a *left* action $p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot f) = (p_1 \cdot p_2) \cdot f$.
To see why, consider these 2 permutations:

$\color{tomato}{p_1(1) = 1, p_1(2) = 3, p_1(3) = 2} $

$\color{tomato}{p_2(1) = 3, p_2(2) = 2, p_2(3) = 1}.$

Let's write out explicitly what the actions are in the two cases to see the difference.

First, let's work out what the compositions $p_1 \cdot p_2$ and $p_2 \cdot p_1$ are.

The composition $p_1 \cdot p_2$ is: $\qquad p_1(p_2(1)) = 2, p_1(p_2(2)) = 3, p_1(p_2(3)) = 1$

while the composition $p_2 \cdot p_1$ is: $\qquad  p_2(p_1(1)) = 3, p_2(p_1(2)) = 1, p_2(p_1(3)) = 2.$

Observe that they are *not* the same.  We will use these later.

Now let's look at the 2 actions.  The first action is on *vectors*.  By the definition of the first action, $$p_1 \cdot (v_1, \color{magenta}{v_2}, \color{limegreen}{v_3}) = (v_{\LARGE{p_1(1)}}, \color{limegreen}{v_{{\LARGE{p_1(2)}}}}, \color{magenta}{v_{\LARGE{p_1(3)}}}) = (v_1, \color{limegreen}{v_3}, \color{magenta}{v_2}). $$

In words: $p_1$ acting on a vector *interchanges the second and third coordinates*.  Similarly, $$p_2 \cdot (v_1, v_2, v_3) = (v_3, v_2, v_1). \tag{♥} $$ In words: $p_2$ acting on a vector *interchanges the first and third coordinates*.

In this situation, I find that thinking in words reduces the confusion:  $p_1$ interchanges the *second and third coordinates*, not $v_2$ and $v_3$.  You'll see the difference below. Hence:

$\begin{align} p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot v) = p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot (v_1, v_2, v_3)) = by (♥) = p_1 \cdot (v_3, \color{magenta}{v_2}, \color{limegreen}{v_1}) & =  (v_3, \color{limegreen}{v_1}, \color{magenta}{v_2}) \tag{☼}\\ & \neq (v_{\LARGE{p_1(1)}}, v_{{\LARGE{p_1(2)}}}, v_{\LARGE{p_1(3)}}). \end{align} $

If the last equality seems wrong, use the "words" description of $p_1$: Interchange the second and third coordinates.)

Question: Does $p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot v)  = (p_2 \cdot p_1) \cdot v$ or  $(p_1 \cdot p_2) \cdot v$? Don't need to calculate these two.
 Just look at the orange to determine if $(v_3, \color{limegreen}{v_1}, \color{magenta}{v_2})$ in $(☼)$ is $(v_{\Large{p_1(p_2)(1)}},v_{\Large{p_1(p_2)(2)}}, ...)$ or $(v_{\Large{p_2(p_1)(1)}}, v_{\Large{p_2(p_1)(2)}}, ...)$.

Conclusion: For the first action, on vectors, $p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot v) = (p_2 \cdot p_1) \cdot v$.
So this is not a left action, but a right action.

---

Now look at the second action, which is not on vectors, but on *real-valued functions on the set of all vectors*. By definition, $$(p_1 \cdot f)(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f(x_{\LARGE{p_1(1)}}, x_{\LARGE{p_1(2)}}, x_{\LARGE{p_1(3)}}) = f(x_1, x_3, x_2).$$

In words: To evaluate $p_1$ applied to a function at a vector, interchange the second and third coordinates of the vector, then apply the function.

Similarly, for $p_2$, $(p_2 \cdot f)(\color{limegreen}{x_1}, x_2, \color{magenta}{x_3}) = f(\color{magenta}{x_{\LARGE{p_2(1)}}}, x_{\LARGE{p_2(2)}}, \color{limegreen}{x_{\LARGE{p_2(3)}}}) = f(\color{magenta}{x_3}, x_2, \color{limegreen}{x_1})$

The words version is: To evaluate $p_2$ applied to a function at a vector, interchange the first and third coordinates of the vector, then apply the function.

So what is $p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot f)$, applied to a vector?  It is $$ \begin{align} (p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot f))(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (p_2 \cdot f)(\color{limegreen}{x_1}, x_3, \color{magenta}{x_2}) & = f(\color{magenta}{x_2}, x_3, \color{limegreen}{x_1}) \\ & \neq f(x_{\LARGE{p_2(1)}}, v_{{\LARGE{p_2(3)}}}, v_{\LARGE{p_2(2)}}). \end{align} $$

(Again, using the "words" description may reduce the confusion.)  Now is this last term $p_1 \cdot p_2$ or $p_2 \cdot p_1$ applied to $f$?  It is the former, as you can see from the orange calculations of $p_1 \cdot p_2$ above.

Conclusion: $p_1 \cdot (p_2 \cdot f) = (p_1 \cdot p_2) \cdot f$.  This one is a left action.

---

I hope this clears up why these two cases aren't the same.  Of course, I haven't yet proven that these are actions in general (I've only illustrated it for the particular $p_1$ and $p_2$ above), but hopefully this will give you the right idea for the general proof.

The key point is to remember that with these definitions, we are permuting the *coordinates of the vector* according to $p$, rather than the *indices of the $v$'s* according to $p$.  If we did the latter instead, then the left and right action cases above would be reversed.  See [alias vs alibi](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic446952.files/aliasalibi.pdf) for more discussion of this point.

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.